# How to wait until all the async calls are completed

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have a ScheduledTaskAgent project the oninvoke() method in ScheduledAgent.cs calls the fetchcurrentdetails() method in a custom defined Class Library project.

In this public string fetchcurrentdetails() method It has the following series of  events.

```
            //class variables
            string strAddress = string.empty;
             public string fetchcurrentdetails()
              {
                GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
                if (watcher.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Granted)
                 {
                  watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);    
                 }
                 return strAddress ;
              }

           private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
             {
            WebClient bWC = new WebClient();                
            System.Uri buri = new Uri("http://dev.virtual//...");
            bWC.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(buri.ToString()));
            bWC.DownloadStringCompleted += new                    DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(bHttpsCompleted);
           }


          private void bHttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs bResponse)
              {
             //do some data extraction and return the string
             strAddress = "This is extracted data";
             }
```

the return statement always returns empty string to calling statement.Any idea how to make sure the execution retains in the class library until the method/event bHttpsCompleted() is completed ? Or what is the way to return the value when the event/method  bHttpsCompleted() is fired.

Comment: I can make this work but quick question.  When is fetchcurrentdetails being called?  Is it a onetime deal where  you just want to get a position?  Or do you want to fetch geocoordinates continually as they change?

Comment: Also, are you after Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8?

Comment: I want to develop this application for windows phone 7 and also wants to make sure it works in windows phone 8.Currently I am using PeriodicTask in this Windows Phone 7 project and it could only fire for every 30 mins :-(  .When it fires the oninvoke() method, this method has a call to fetchcurrentdetails() method as its first statement.From there I have described in my post how the code looks like in fetchcurrentdetails() method in class library.It would be great if I can capture the geocoordinates events continually as they change.But I don't think it is possible to do that in Windws phone7.

Comment: With Async CTP its possible

Comment: @mahantesh how can I modify this code with async ctp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify like this

```
public Task<string> fetchcurrentdetails()
    {

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
        if (watcher.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Granted)
        {
            watcher.PositionChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    WebClient bWC = new WebClient();
                    System.Uri buri = new Uri("http://dev.virtual//...");
                    bWC.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(buri.ToString()));
                    bWC.DownloadStringCompleted += (s1, e1) =>
                    {

                        if (e1.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e1.Error);
                        else if (e1.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                        else
                            tcs.TrySetResult(e1.Result);
                        //do some data extraction and return the string                          
                    };
                };
        }
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Call : `await fetchcurrentdetails()`

Comment: Able to install system.threading.tasks from      http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks

Comment: In calling .cs file it says "cannot find all types required by async keyword"

Comment: got resolved by installing PM: install-package Microsoft.Bcl.Async –pre

Answer (score -1):

You should do your return from the bHttpsCompleted function.

Comment: The control is not waiting till the bHttpsCompleted() method gets completed.